# Calculate total width of child elements in more than one class using jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm haviing following code

```
 <span class="numbers">
    <a href="#">20</a>, <a href="#">50</a>, <a href="#">100</a>
 </span>
```

class "numbers" is position absolute element & its using more than one time in a page.

Content inside class"numbers" will be dynamically changing. So I need to apply total width of children to its parent container

I tried this code but not working.

```
var totalWidth = 0;
$(".numbers").children('a').each(function() {
      totalWidth = totalWidth + $(this).width();
      $('.numbers').each(function(){$(this).css("width", totalWidth);});
});
```

But I'm getting totalWidth value 0 only. Can any one help please..........?

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/contactsreejesh/xP3mn/6/

Comment: Are you sure that you need javascript for this? make the a-tags blocks and floating to the left, and the parent-container should resize as the content changes.

Comment: No, because I'm using ".numbers" many times across my page. So its width should be dynamically changing. & most importantly its position:absolute element.

Comment: Your code is actually working for me - can you set up a fiddle with the problem or link us to a live page?

Comment: Hi, I have setup a jsFiddel pls see.  http://jsfiddle.net/contactsreejesh/xP3mn/

Comment: @sri Your code is working for me on [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emosaurusrex/xP3mn/1/).

Comment: @Snuffleupagus Did you see the text? Number 100 is on next line. I need all text to be in one line

Comment: @sri You have commas and spaces outside of the `a` element that aren't getting added into the width.

Comment: @Snuffleupagus.. Oops I didn't noticed that. Thanks.. But I think the issue is still getting more. If I use more than one class its will be a problem... See http://jsfiddle.net/contactsreejesh/xP3mn/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to loop over all the `numbers` elements. Then within that loop, loop over the children that belong to each individual `numbers` span

```
$('.numbers').each(function() {
    var totalWidth = 0;
    /* "this" in this loop is the current numbers span*/
    var $self=$(this) 
   /* loop over all the children of this element*/
    $self.children('a').each(function() { 
        /* "this" in current loop is an A tag*/
        totalWidth += $(this).width();      
    });

    /* now set width*/
    $self.width( totalWidth)

})
```

This statement will affect all the elements with the class in whole page and they would all have the same width

```
$('.numbers').width(totalWidth);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You code worked perfectly for me. I just played around it. http://jsfiddle.net/xP3mn/9/

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FGmYU/

the change is this:

```
totalWidth += $(this).width();
```

The input shows you that the calculated width is 56.

Comment: That's not the issue. review your answer to avoid getting downvoted

Comment: Seems to be i answered the question.  It was an accidental submit, if its still not right, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me as per [here](http://jsfiddle.net/emosaurusrex/S6h9J/1).

```
var w = 0;
$('.numbers').find('a').each(function(){
    w += $(this).width();
});​​​​​​
```